# SwiftUI .position modifier with coordinates

Tags: swift, swiftui, position, viewmodifier

I want to place items on an image with the modifier `.position` using the coordinates of each item. But when I look at the rendering, I don't understand the logic of the position of the items , what formula is used to place the items on the image and what frame of reference is being used. My code:

```
ZStack {
    Image(self.schema.image)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .border(Color.white)
        .shadow(color: self.colorShadow ? Color.green : Color.gray.opacity(0.5) ,radius: 10)
        .overlay(
            ForEach(self.schema.item) { item in
                Text(String(item.id))
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .padding(5)
                    .overlay(
                        Circle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                    .offset(x: 20, y: 100)
                    .position(x: CGFloat(item.coordinatesX), y: CGFloat(item.coordinatesY))
            }
    )
}
```

My coordinates:

```
Items(id: 1, name: "1", coordinatesX: 0, coordinatesY: 50),
Items(id: 2, name: "2", coordinatesX: 10, coordinatesY: 50),
Items(id: 3, name: "3", coordinatesX: 20, coordinatesY: 50),
Items(id: 4, name: "4", coordinatesX: 30, coordinatesY: 50),
Items(id: 5, name: "5", coordinatesX: 40, coordinatesY: 50),
Items(id: 6, name: "6", coordinatesX: 50, coordinatesY: 50),
Items(id: 7, name: "7", coordinatesX: 60, coordinatesY: 50),
Items(id: 8, name: "8", coordinatesX: 70, coordinatesY: 50)
```

The final result:

[image]

I don't understand why it's a diagonal. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need container in overlay, like

```
.overlay(ZStack {
    ForEach(self.schema.item) { item in
        Text(String(item.id))
            .font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .padding(5)
            .overlay(
                Circle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .offset(x: 20, y: 100)
            .position(x: CGFloat(item.coordinatesX), y: CGFloat(item.coordinatesY))
    }
})
```